# Javascript Input Value Is Undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to reference an input from my HTML through Javascript, and for some reason no matter what I enter in this text field it always returns undefined... why is this so?

Javascript:

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const code = document.getElementById("textArea").value;


if (button === null) {
    alert("Button is null");
} else if (code === null) {
    alert("Code is null");
}

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Submitted!");
    console.log(code);
});

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Submitted!");
    getInputValue();
});
```

HTML:

````
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Code Sorter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id = "textArea" rows = "10" cols = "50" placeholder="Type something..."></textarea>
    <button id="button" value = "submit">Submit</button>
    <script src = main.js></script>
</body>

</html>```
````

Comment: You're retrieving the value on pageload, when the value is empty. Retrieve it inside the event handlers instead

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you remove the .value from the .getElementById and put it on the button.addEventListener, it works:

```
const button = document.getElementById("button");
const code = document.getElementById("textArea");

if (button === null) {
    alert("Button is null");
} else if (code === null) {
    alert("Code is null");
}

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Submitted!");
    console.log(code.value);
});

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("Submitted!");
    getInputValue();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple.
First: How often do you set the variable code? Once, at the start, when it will always be undefined. Just because textfield.value changes does not mean that `code` is reevaluated.

The solution is to get the text from within your button handler.

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
    console.log("Submitted!");
    console.log(document.getElementById("textArea").value)});
```